# Confused about rails 4 asset pipeline with respect to third party js libraries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have two questions, but I am guessing they both lead to the same answer.

They both are related to the fact that static images, show up in development mode and not on production (heroku).

Case 1:

In my model.rb

```
has_attached_file :avatar, styles: {
    thumb: '32x32#',
    medium: '512x512#'
}, 
:default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('/assets/avatar_:style.png') ## <- This line (#1)
```

Case 2:

In my view.html.haml I have inline javascript

```
:javascript
 $('.star').raty({
    path: '/assets', ### <- This line (#2)
    readOnly: true,
    noRatedMsg : "I haven't been rated yet!",
    score: function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-score');
  }
});
```

In **CASE 1**, I am trying to implement a default image if a user does not upload a profile pic(using paperclip), with two images `avatar_thumb.png` and `avatar_medium.png` inside of `/app/assets/images`

In **CASE 2**, I am trying to implement 5star rating feature using a third party library [raty](http://wbotelhos.com/raty), which requires the "*star*" images. I have placed three images that come with this library in `/app/assets/images` as well.

**Question** : In both the cases the images are seen in development mode, but not when i deploy to Heroku. How do i resolve this.

P.S.:  I am absolutely new to rails, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asset pipeline does not make your life easy here - Paperclip assumes that `default_url` is something where it can replace the `:style` portion with the required value, but this can't work since that would obviously change the fingerprint portion of the filename as well.

The easiest thing to do here is not use the asset pipeline for those images. You don't have to use the asset pipeline for anything really and the benefit for images is pretty minimal compared to javascript or css files.

To do this move the images into `public/images`. Then, for the first case change the default url to

```
/images/avatar_:style.png
```

and for the second case set the path to `/images`

You could make the second case work with the asset pipeline if you wanted to - something like

```
:javascript
  $('.star').raty({
    readOnly: true,
    starHalf: '#{asset_path('star-half.png')}',
    starOff: '#{asset_path('star-off.png')}',
    starOn: '#{asset_path('star-on.png')}',
    cancelOn: '#{asset_path('cancel-on.png')}',
    cancelOff: '#{asset_path('cancel-off.png')}',
    noRatedMsg : "I haven't been rated yet!",
    score: function() {
      return $(this).attr('data-score');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @Frederick, that did it. I had lost hope on this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new, let me describe how it works for you:

--

**Assets**

When you deploy a Rails application, your `assets` will be part of what's known as the [`asset pipeline`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html). In development, your asset files are stored in `app/assets/...`

When you use the [`asset path helpers`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html), Rails will call the following paths for you:

- `app/assets/...`
- `vendor/assets/...`
- `public/...`

The problem you have is in development, with all your assets present in `app/assets`, you'll be able to call all the files you wish indiscriminately

--

**Production**

When you run your app in `production` mode, things get a little trickier

Firstly, you can't rely on your assets being in `app/assets` any more - production mode generally (not always, but on Heroku for sure) means that you will have to [`precompile`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline) your assets:

> In production, Rails precompiles these files to public/assets by
>   default. The precompiled copies are then served as static assets by
>   the web server. The files in app/assets are never served directly in
>   production.

This means if you want to load assets in production, especially on Heroku, you will need to use the `asset_paths` correctly (mainly because Rails will [`fingerprint`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) your production / compiled assets)

--

**Fix**

In reference to your question directly, I would do this:

1

```
:default_url => asset_path('avatar_:style.png') #-> not sure about the :style part here
```

2

```
:javascript
 $('.star').raty({
    path: asset_url, #-> will use the asset_url
    readOnly: true,
    noRatedMsg : "I haven't been rated yet!",
    score: function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-score');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rich. On implementing the changes you suggested I see the following errors: Case 1 -  `undefined method `asset_path' for #<Class:0x000001087d5178>` and for `Case 2` the images do not show up and on firebug the following errors are seen - `ReferenceError: asset_url is not defined`

Comment: So effectively this does not work. :( Any other ideas?